# Where can I find actual data for the hysteresis of a magnetic material?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

When a magnet is exposed to an external magnetic field it can be further magnetized or demagnetized. This amount can be found by looking at the hysteresis curve for that magnet. I do not have the magnet to experimentally find this hysteresis curve, but I would imagine that there has already been work done to find the hysteresis of certain materials. The problem is I can't find any real measured data for these materials.

I either need measured values of the hysteresis for a real magnet (applied H field vs the intrinsic B that the magnet contributes to the overall B field) or alternatively a Jiles-Atherton model with all of the parameters for a real magnet.

Ideally I would like the data for an alnico 5 magnet, but I've been searching for actual data for so long that I'm doubting that there is any available on the internet. If I can get data for a B vs H curve for any hard magnetic material, or a completed Jiles-Atherton model for any hard magnetic material I will be happy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about looking up material parameters, and not physics.

Comment: Does [this image count](http://www.magnets.com.cn/mats_pic/H/Hysteresis_Loop_of_AlNiCo.jpg)?

Comment: I think looking up physically relevant parameters is an important part of physics. Even better, this is asking *where* to look up parameters, which amounts to asking for a tool that can be used for all sorts of physics.